# DHT11 not working with LED in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, led

the point of my code is to turn on a LED when the humidity level reaches a certain amount. However it reads the amount of humidity but the LED is not turning on. Why isn't it working??

```
#include <SimpleDHT.h>

// for DHT11,
//      VCC: 5V or 3V
//      GND: GND
//      DATA: 2
int pinDHT11 = 2;
SimpleDHT11 dht11;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  }

void loop() {
  // start working...
  Serial.println("=================================");
  Serial.println("Sample DHT11...");

  // read without samples.
  byte temperature = 0;
  byte humidity = 0;
  int err = SimpleDHTErrSuccess;

  if (humidity > 70 ) {
     digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  }
  else if ((err = dht11.read(pinDHT11, &temperature, &humidity, NULL)) != SimpleDHTErrSuccess) {
    Serial.print("Read DHT11 failed, err="); Serial.println(err);delay(1000);
    return;
  }

  Serial.print("Sample OK: ");
  Serial.print((int)temperature); Serial.print(" *C, ");
  Serial.print((int)humidity); Serial.println(" H");

  // DHT11 sampling rate is 1HZ.
  delay(1500);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the schematic

Comment: why do you expect it to light? ... you set the humidity to zero just before you check if it is above 70

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because in fact error statement reads the value of temperature and humidity sensor.

You set the `humidity` and `temperature` variables to 0. If statement compares this variables to 70, before actually reading sensor data.

I haven't tested but this should work.

```
#include <SimpleDHT.h>

int pinDHT11 = 2;
SimpleDHT11 dht11;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    // start working...
    Serial.println("=================================");
    Serial.println("Sample DHT11...");

    // read without samples.
    byte temperature = 0;
    byte humidity = 0;

    int err = SimpleDHTErrSuccess;
    if ((err = dht11.read(pinDHT11, &temperature, &humidity, NULL))
        != SimpleDHTErrSuccess)
    {
        Serial.print("Read DHT11 failed, err=");
        Serial.println(err);
        delay(1000);
        return;
    }

    Serial.print("Sample OK: ");
    Serial.print((int)temperature);
    Serial.print(" *C, ");
    Serial.print((int)humidity);
    Serial.println(" H");

    if (humidity > 70 )
    {
        Serial.println("Humidity is above 70%");
        digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Humidity is below 70%");
    }
    // DHT11 sampling rate is 1HZ.
    delay(1500);
}
```

Comment: hi, unfortuantly this code does not work, but thank you. It delivers me with the error message 'exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'SimpleDHT11::read(byte*, byte*, NULL)'

Comment: @Miri, It’s fixed in the answer now by adding `DHT11pin` to the `dht11.read()` call. This is very basic troubleshooting and you could have fixed this yourself.